# A question on mixed boundary value problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I was wondering if there exists a classical solution ($C^2$) to the problem
\begin{align}
-Lu&=1,\text{in}~\Omega\nonumber\\
u&=0,\text{on}~\Gamma_1\nonumber\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}&=0,\text{on}~\Gamma_2\nonumber
\end{align}
where $L$ is a linear second order differential opeartor with variable coefficients which are Lipshitz continuous, $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2=\partial\Omega$, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: This depends on the smoothness of $\Omega$, and on the set, where the different boundary conditions meet.

Comment: The boundary and the domain are say $C^2$ in nature. Can it be inferred that the solution is classical now?. Can I at least have an idea/reference to this?.